# Combine Data from two services using concatMap

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have two services and the data from the first is used to retrieve data from the second.  I'm having trouble accessing a specific value from the data obtained from the first service that is used to get data from the second service.  Angular doesn't like 'firstserviceResultsJson.indSsn'.  However I need to send that data to the second service.  Any ideas how to get data from first service into second service?

```
    this.firstService(query).pipe(
      .firstServiceMethod(query).pipe(
        concatMap(firstServiceResultsJson => this.secondService.secondServiceMethod(firstServiceResultsJson.specificParameter))
      )
    .subscribe(combinedResults => (this.finalResultsToSendToView = combinedResults ));
```

Comment: I quite don't get this syntax `this.firstService(query).pipe(
      .firstServiceMethod(query).pipe(` As per my knowledge you can only use operators within  the`pipe`. Are you sure, this is the right code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `firstServiceMethod` returns the correct object for you to be able to access a property on the result. Then use a `concatMap` with a resultSelector to output the result of both the outer and inner observables. Example:

```js
this.firstService
  .firstServiceMethod(query)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(
      firstServiceResultsJson =>
        this.secondService.secondServiceMethod(firstServiceResultsJson.specificParameter),
      (outer, inner) => [outer, inner]
    )
  )
  .subscribe(
    combinedResults => (this.finalResultsToSendToView = combinedResults)
  );
```

### [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tdtpce)

Comment: @M Jenkins please consider accepting this answer if you feel that it answers your question.

Comment: Done  Thank you.